# Protractor: cleanup after test suite is finished

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, protractor, end-to-end

In my "conf.js" test suites are arranged as follows(using saucelab's webdriver):

```
suites: {
    abc: './abc/spec.js',
    xyz: './xyz/spec.js',
    pqr: './pqr/spec.js'
},
```

The problem with above arrangement is if one of the alert box/window unexpectedly appears in one of the test suite,test suites after that particular suite suffer and start failing.

Is there an in-built way in protractor to close all windows/alert box etc. when a test suite is finished or it can only be handled manually?

Comment: Could you please add more details about how do they fail? Stacktrace would be good to see.

Comment: Suppose an unexpected popup opens in abc/spec.js and it was not handled in the script. So, if in /xyz/spec.js it wants to click a button, it could not click it because of the unhandled pop-up opened in previous spec. What I want is a way to handle all these unexpected alert to be cleaned up before starting the next suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, there is no place in `protractor` to provide "before test suite" or "after test suite" logic (correct me if I'm wrong about it).

The idea is to use `afterEach()`, try switching to the [alert](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.Alert), [`dismiss()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.Alert.prototype.dismiss) it if exists (or [`accept()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.Alert.prototype.accept) depending on what you need), do nothing if does not exist:

```
describe("My test", function () {
    afterEach(function () {
        browser.switchTo().alert().then(
            function (alert) { 
                alert.dismiss(); 
            },
            function (err) {}
        );
    });

    it("Test smth", function () {
        // ...
    });
});
```

See also:

- [Protractor Dismiss Alerts If Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041270/protractor-dismiss-alerts-if-open)

Comment: This is one way but not very efficient as it will slow down the test suite because of check after each "it". For my purpose,I can add one more "it" after the last "it" testcase and that will do the job.

Comment: My purpose was asking the question was to know whether protractor has inbuilt support and as I  can understand as of now protractor has no support for it.

Comment: @AmanGupta good, well, there is also an option to make protractor restart the browser every time using `restartBrowserBetweenTests` setting, but it would slow down your tests dramatically. As for the alerts, you have to close them manually anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I have written which handles multiple windows and unexpected alerts.It does not closes the main window as it is required in the next test suite.

```
this.cleanUp = function(){
        browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles){
            for(var i=handles.length-1;i>-1;i--){
                browser.switchTo().window(handles[i]);
                browser.switchTo().alert().then(function(alert){
                    alert.dismiss();
                },function(err){});
                if(i)
                    browser.close();
            }
        },function(err){});
    };
```